# Aligning integers in a table with doubles and integers

Tags: tables, align, tabularx, dcolumn

I have the following table:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{afterpage}


\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}




\begin{document}



\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\scriptsize
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\caption{My caption}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{5}{D{.}{.}{6}}}
\toprule
& \mcc[1]{1 (L)}
& \mcc[1]{2}
& \mcc[1]{3}
& \mcc[1]{4}
& \mcc[1]{5 (H)} \\
\midrule


\multicolumn{5}{l}{\textbf{This panel's title}}\\
\midrule
A (floats)   $\beta$ &-0.49 &-0.17 &-0.01 & 0.16 & 0.47 \\
B (floats)   &6.43 &6.91 &6.98 &6.92 &6.48 \\
C (integers) &136 &241 &342 &441 &536 \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

The table contains both doubles and integers and aligns floats by the `.`. However, I find that it looks a bit odd with the integers being left-aligned. Is it possible to have them right-aligned? Or aligning it somehow so it doesn't look as weird as now.

[image]

Comment: they are right aligned to the implicit decimal point, not left aligned.  If the values down a column are not relating to the same data there is an argument that they shouldn't be aligned at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

With use of the `siunitx` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs, siunitx}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}

\begin{document}



\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    %\scriptsize
    \sisetup{table-format=-1.2,
             table-text-alignment=right}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\caption{My caption}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{5}{S} }
\toprule
    & \mcc{1 (L)}   & \mcc{2}  & \mcc{3}    & \mcc{4}   & \mcc{5 (H)}   \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\textbf{This panel's title}}\\
\midrule
A (floats)   $\beta$ 
                & -0.49 & -0.17 & -0.01 & 0.16 &  0.47 \\
B (floats)      &  6.43 &  6.91 &  6.98 &6.92  &  6.48 \\
C (integers)    & {136} & {241} & {342} & {44} & {536} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```